# Psmouse serio1: failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1

Tags: 18.04, live-usb

I’m installing Ubuntu 18.04 using a USB. After the installation was finished I restarted as prompted, and it booted to a black screen.

[image: black screen]

The screen has been stuck at this screen for 20 minutes now. How can I proceed with the installation?

Comment: What mouse do you use? Can you explain in more details?